# Oracle PL SQL: using labels to get out of for loops

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop, plsql, label

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
  <<outer_loop>>
  FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
    FOR i IN 1..3 LOOP
      EXIT outer_loop WHEN outer_loop.i = 3;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('outer i is:' || outer_loop.i || ' inner i is: ' ||i);
      GOTO goodbye;
    END LOOP;       
  END LOOP;
  <<goodbye>>
  NULL;
END;
/
```

I have the code above and it gives the result below, but my notes say to NEVER do this. Why is this the case? It does work after all.

```
anonymous block completed
outer i is:1 inner i is: 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GOTO is considered as poor programming practice. It came from old times when older programming languages didn't have a lot of structure and programmers were forced to use a lot of GOTO.

The GOTO leads to what is known as spaghetti code.  It's hard to read and hard to
understand.

Answer (score 6):

Usage of `GOTO` is discouraged in almost every language, mostly because it damages readability of your code, yes, and in your case it's even worse — you are jumping through two levels of stack.

Apart from it, PL/SQL has this feature you would have noticed were you not using `GOTO`. It is rarely useful, but the notation from your code is used exactly for this.

Say, you have two loops nested this way.

```
BEGIN
  <<outer>>
  FOR i IN 1..2 LOOP
    <<inner>>
    FOR j IN 1..2 LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line('In inner loop');
    END LOOP;

    dbms_output.put_line('In outer loop');
  END LOOP;

  dbms_output.put_line('Finished');
END;
```

Obviously, the output will be

```
In inner loop
In inner loop
In outer loop
In inner loop
In inner loop
In outer loop
Finished
```

Sometimes you need to exit loop before it is finished "normally", so you add `EXIT;`.

```
BEGIN
  <<outer>>
  FOR i IN 1..2 LOOP
    <<inner>>
    FOR j IN 1..2 LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line('In inner loop');
      EXIT;
    END LOOP;

    dbms_output.put_line('In outer loop');
  END LOOP;

  dbms_output.put_line('Finished');
END;
```

which results in only one execution of nested loop for each iteration of outer loop.

```
In inner loop
In outer loop
In inner loop
In outer loop
Finished
```

But you might want to abort your processing at all, and for that you can either set some flag variable in nested loop and check its value in outer loop, or you can specify which loop you are exiting exactly.

```
BEGIN
  <<outer>>
  FOR i IN 1..2 LOOP
    <<inner>>
    FOR j IN 1..2 LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line('In inner loop');
      EXIT outer;
    END LOOP;

    dbms_output.put_line('In outer loop');
  END LOOP;

  dbms_output.put_line('Finished');
END;
```

This way you exit both loops.

```
In inner loop
Finished
```

Back to your example, if you eliminate GOTO, you will exit from both loops on third iteration of inner loop.

I would not say this is great for readability, and I would rather somehow notified outer loop of something special than had inner loop taking responsibility for exiting from outer one.